# .NET written console app dependencies

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, dependencies, 64bit, 32bit

I have written a freeware console app in VB.net, which I have fine-tuned and successfully tested in headless Raspberry Pi Bullseye. I have also written a installation script after checking its dependencies (https://bit.ly/multilarm-linux). However, on a fresh emulation (Raspberry Pi Bookworm emulation on VirtualBox), despite installing the dependencies (which to be fair, does not install new packages apart from Bass drivers), ldd outputs as follows:

```
admin@raspberry:~ $ ldd ./Multilarm
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff501f5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8fa34d1000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8fa34cb000)
libz.so.1 => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8fa34c1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8fa34a7000)
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8fa3361000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8fa318d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8fa3f87000)
```

I have tried installing lib64z1 and lib32stdc++6 with no avail. My app already contains the .net framework files as a single package. I am wondering whether this problem has to do anything with the fact that the RPi kernel is 64-bit (uname -m x86_64) running in a 32 bit namespace.

```
admin@raspberry:~ $ locate libz.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
admin@raspberry:~ $ locate libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted: needed 64-bit libraries:

```
aptDepends=( 
               zlib1g:amd64
               lib32stdc++6:amd64
               libasound2-plugins:amd64
           )

sudo apt-get install -y "${aptDepends[@]}"
```